# The container background is longer than usual

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

So i created a footer with a green background and added a green backgroun inside a container as you can see on the image. But somehow the length of the green is longer than the other container.

[image]
CODE HERE

HTML
[image]
CSS[image]

Comment: add your code  to the question with CTRL+ K

Comment: it does not work, i tried before making this post. Sorry

Comment: can you show the div before the footer css & html , i think that there an padding or margin  that is applied on it but not on the footer

Comment: at least add it to: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest put your **`green`** class inside **`container`** not with **`container`**. Check below snippet, you will see the difference.

```css
.green {
  background: green;
}

.container {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="green">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-5">5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: Im new to this site but i think i did it now :) and again, thnx for the help

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your html code it seems that you are using twitter bootstrap framework.

if you want to use the column structure then you should follow the markup standard set by bootstrap

***HTML STRUCTURE***

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      HTML code 
    </div>
  </div>
<div>
```

don't forget to set the hierarchy as per standards.

checkout the documentation for more details https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I added the <div class="row"> but its still the same.